# Non-uniform circular motion and how external force affects the motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, constrained-dynamics

[image: Non-Uniform Circular Motion]

If there is a force angled inwards acting on the object in circular motion counterclockwise, and the force is split into 2 components, the tangential and the radial, how does each component force affect the motion of the object?

From problems I've done, it appears that only the tangential component of the force is affecting the motion of the object, and that is used to calculate the tangential acceleration of the said object. Why can the radial component of the force be ignored?

Comment: *"Why can the radial component of the force be ignored?"* - you've stipulated that the object is in (not necessarily uniform) *circular* motion.  Think about the implication of that stipulation for the radial component.

Answer (score 0):

The radial component of force just keeps the particle moving in a circle (as opposed to a straight line, which it would do otherwise).

In a typical circular motion problem, something in the premise of the problem allows you to take for granted that there will be the right amount of radial force to keep the particle moving in a circle. For example, if the particle is confined to a circular track, the track applies whatever radial force is needed. That's why you can ignore it in calculations.

Of course, there are some problems where you can't take for granted that the particle is moving in a circle at all. In those cases, you may have to calculate the radial component of force, and if it's not the right amount required to maintain the circular motion, the particle will go off along some different trajectory.

Answer (score 0):

The radial component of the external force provides the required centripetal force to keep the object moving in a circle wheras the tangential component increases the linear speed of the object.

In some cases the radial component of the force is not enough to provide the required centripetal acceleration to the body due to which the object doesn't continues circular motion.

Answer (score 0):

consider a particle constrained to move on a circular wire.
let's attach a force as you mentioned.
the tangential force will accelerate the particle, but the particle is constrained on the wire.

the radial component is balanced by the centrifugal force.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mass tied with a rope to the center of the circle, as a slingshot, the radial force will push the body towards the center, but the centrifugal force will immediately bring it back to its previous trajectory, limited by the length of the rope. The only component which has a lasting effect is the tangential component which increases the speed of the mass.

Answer (score 0):

- The **tangential** force component is **not** the only one that affects the motion. But it is the only one that affects the *speed*, the velocity magnitude. It is the only one that affects the "how fast" part.
- The **radial** force component affects the motion as well. But only its *direction* of the velocity. It is the only component that affects the "which way" part.

If you want to find **tangential acceleration** then you are looking for how fast the object speeds up. Not how much it turns. Only how much its velocity magnitude changes. Thus only the tangential force component is relevant since the radial component doesn't influence speed but only direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can decide to accept this as an answer or not. In the $xy$ plane you can express the location of the particle as $\vec r=\rho \vec i_{\rho}$ where if the motion of the particle is strictly circular motion, the radial distance $\rho$ may be substituted by a constant $c$. The radial unit vector $\vec i_{\rho}=\vec i_{x}\cos\phi+\vec i_{y}\sin\phi$ where $\phi(t)$ is the polar angle (measured from the $x$ axis) and $t$ denotes time. Since the motion is circular $\dot \rho=0$. However $\dot \phi =\omega\neq 0$. Thus
$$\vec v=\frac{d\vec r}{dt}=c\frac{d}{dt}\vec i_{\rho}=c\omega(-\vec i_{x}\sin\phi+\vec i_{y}\cos\phi)$$
Subsequently
$$\vec a=\frac{d\vec v}{dt}=-c\omega^{2}(\vec i_{x}\cos\phi+\vec i_{y}\sin\phi)=-c\omega^{2}\vec{i}_{\rho}$$
Therefore, once the particle is bound to have exactly circular motion, it will experience force only in the radial direction. Tangential forces show up only when the radius of motion changes.